# Proxmox backup to wasabi

Tags: backup, proxmox, wasabi, wasabi-hot-cloud-storage

In my company we are deciding to move part of our backups to the cloud, and in particular, as the title suggests, we have configured wasabi backup.
The first urgency is to move the backups to the proxmox inside the company on wasabi, but looking on the documentation and online I can't find a way to move the backups from the proxmox to wasabi.
Do you have any suggestions or advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We're looking to accomplish something similar with Proxmox and Wasabi. After some digging this afternoon, the most mature way of doing this would be to use Veeam with Agent Backup. Veeam does not officially support the Proxmox kernel, explained by staff [here](https://forums.veeam.com/veeam-agents-for-linux-mac-aix-solaris-f41/proxmox-incremental-backups-with-veeam-t66702.html), and it doesn't seem like they have any intention of doing so. This means you cannot back up the VM/CTs from the hypervisor level (reliably). But, it seems that you can leverage the Agent Backup instead, and use the VBS (Veeam Backup Server) to push incremental backups to Wasabi. I use Veeam and Wasabi together with some clientele on ESXi for a 3-2-1 backup scheme with Agent Backups, works great. This is the approach we're going to take with Proxmox as well. Although it's more expensive than some cheap workaround, this backup method scales very well considering you can use VEM to manage other VBSs.

EDIT: Here's a few links to Veeam resources to check out:

- [Veeam Agent Backup](https://helpcenter.veeam.com/docs/agentforlinux/userguide/overview.html?ver=50) (Linux version, but they make a Windows and Mac agent too.)
- [General VBR Resource Page](https://www.veeam.com/documentation-guides-datasheets.html)

Comment: Thanks Alex...these days, since I was in the testing phase I solved this way, I downloaded the backups from proxmox on a buffalo server, and then with a python script I communicated via s3 with wasabi and wrote the backups.
Now I will propose the solution in the company so as to avoid the use of scripts and rely on veeam